# Fixing the axes while animating in matlab (not allowing them to change)

Tags: matlab, animation, axis, scaling, axes

I am trying to animate a cube (i wish there was a function for cube along the lines of cylinder() ) moving in 3d space. It has both rotation and translation. While I succeeded in animating, the axes seems to be scaling dynamically. I would like them to stop. I want to fix the axis limits. i want the axis to be constant from the beginning to the end.

I am new to animating. I got a piece of code from the internet that demonstrates animating
demo prog : http://pastebin.com/fbv9gDS2

I edited that so that I can animate a cube. but then i ended up with an animation where the axis was continuously changing.

edited prog: http://pastebin.com/k3cEm4Fq

PS: the links are safe, no spam

Comment: code for the function cube that draws a cube and returns the handle : http://pastebin.com/muCQ4rpT

Comment: you can just set `xlim`, `ylim`, and `zlim` after every draw call. not necessarily the most elegant, but it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the axes by using the `axis` command with specific limits. For example

```
axis( [-2 2 -3 3 -4 4] );
```

sets the axes limits for `'x'` in the range -2,2, for `'y'` in the range -3,3 and for `'z'` in the range -4,4.

Comment: I tried. It did not work. can you please look at the code and tell me where i am going wrong or where to insert that line?

Comment: The example i previously had worked fine. can you please take a look at the code and point out what makes the axes change in the cube program and not in the example? Moreover, If i retained the shape/drawing but made the path bigger, setting bigger limits for axes worked well. but changing the shape to a cube corrupted the axis settings