# Saving figures in Matlab with the same size

Tags: matlab, save-as

I would like to have a sequence of figures from which I can create a video.

```
for i=1:500
    h = figure;
    h.Units = 'inches';
    h.OuterPosition = [0.25 0.25 5 5];
    contourf(data{1});
    saveas  (h ,sprintf('figure_%.3d.png', i));
end
```

I have this code and I successfully save figures. However, some of the figures (maybe 10 out of 500) do not have the same dimension with the other figures.

1. Why do they not have the same size?
2. How do I make sure that all the saved figures have the size dimensions?

Comment: Don't create a new figure for each plot, update the existing plot instead. Call `contourf` once, before the loop, and get the handle it returns. Then update the data that the handle references. This will update the plot without changing the size of the figure or axes.

Comment: can you please show me where I should put the contourf? Does it mean I will have to separately save the first figure?

Comment: Here's an example using `plot`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185082/fix-axes-for-animation -- you can imagine how it'd be using `contourf` instead of `plot`.

Comment: It works, thank you for your help!